# Why does my form not do checks for validation when I set these up?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML:

```
    <form action="/User/Account/Register" class="form" method="post">
            <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="kq_5caRv7pZxBPgvvBiwHzNeQd_V8MvPzr9k85FsDWdhDmBh3yCq5JmofXpqxyhVcWWBfjYuKirpYfoWd_dor_VlpxqAb0AmN4sKSVbDJS1cDWwhI9xodugz-SKaoxmba-ukOw2" />


            <div data-valmsg-summary="true"></div>

            <div id="input-fields">
                <div>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The User name field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 6 characters long." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" type="password" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="white-gradient glossy">Register</button>
        </form>
```

However when I click on Register it doesn't do any of the checks that I expect and the form is submitted without any problem.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are not calling any JavaScript validation routines. This can be done by <form onsubmit='return validate(this);'>

Comment: I thought this would happen automatically with HTML5

Comment: Only on certain fields and for certain inputs i.e. attribute required will ensure that there has been something entered, email will check for a correctly formatted email addres, same with url. But you shouldn't rely on this as not all HTML5 form elements are supported by all browsers.

Comment: along with not all html5 elements being supported, there are instances where some browsers do not prevent submission if html5 validation rules fail

Comment: @Patrick - thanks but I have a backup in my ASP code if the browser does not support the HTML5 elements. I am still confused about when the validation takes place. Jeff suggested I would need code on the form onsubmit but I could not find any other links that mentioned that.

Comment: the only way to validate form inputs on the client side is to use html5 validation rules and/or javascript to check the inputs, onsubmit can be used to execute a javascript function and in that function would be where you validate the inputs. [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because data-val, data-val-required... are not attributes of HTML5 input tag.

View this please:

[HTML5 form additions, validation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML5_form_additions#Validation)